# Combining geometric and binomial distribution on a 3-sided dice

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

Say that I have a 3-sided dice, with different probabilities for each number. I have keep rolling the dice until I roll 3 and then stop. The obvious way to model this is to actually roll the dice until I get a 3, and count the values I get, e.g. using a for-loop.

Now my question is, can I model this as a geometric distribution with the probability of rolling 3, which gives me a number of dice rolls, and then do a binomial distribution on the number I get to determine if the dice rolls before were 1 or 2? Or will this yield different results than the straightforward simulation?

*A bonus question:* How could I prove that these two approaches are either equivalent, or that they yield different results?

Comment: Yes, you can first generate a geometric time of rolling a 3 and then do a symmetric binomial for 1,2. You just decomposed a joint distribution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from the practical difficulties of producing a $3$-sided die, yes, you can do it that way. I would expect that the proof is probably already implicit in how you came up with doing it this way in the first place. If you want to argue more formally, you can derive the binomial distribution from the conditional distribution of a roll given that it's not a $3$.